# Use tag attributes in java code in jsp tag file

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat6, jsp-tags

I have some attributes declared by something like `<%@attribute name="listname" required="true"%>` in the starting in `.tag` file.

I can print that by using `${listname}`. But I want to use this variable in one of the java code inside the same page.

Something like,

```
<%
    String listname = ${listname};
    ...Some more code...
%>
```

How do I do this.

I am using apache tomcat6 if that helps.

I am new to this environment and even Java. Please forgive and correct me if I am using some wrong terminologies.

Comment: The idea of using attributes and JSTL is getting rid of scriptlets (`<% %>`) which make the JSP difficult to understand, edit and/or validate. Use the MVC approach and get all of your logic in the servlet.

Comment: Thanks @SJuan76, I am pretty much doing what you said. But there is no logic here. The code here will be the code to print formatted output based on `listname`. This is the part which view does, right?

Comment: And a side question, how do we pass this kind of attribute directly from servlet? I am passing it from other jsp using tag attributes. And I am familiar with `request.set/getAttribute`.

Comment: You would be better using an appropiate tag. Anyway, attributes are either in the session or the request objects. Depending of where it was set by you, you can just do a `getAttribute("listname")`

Comment: @SJuan76, I am passing it by using `<t:tagname listname='somestring'></t:tagname>`. I tried doing `session.getAttribute("listname")` and `request.getAttribute("listname")` both, but it seems like it is not there.

Answer (score 2):

You can get at attributes passed to custom tags using the attributes from `jspContext` :-

```
<%@ tag description="Category Options" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"  pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ attribute name="depth" required="false" type="java.lang.Integer" rtexprvalue="true"%>

<%
Integer depth = (Integer)jspContext.getAttribute("depth");
// do stuff with depth
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into doing the processing in a Java class instead of a JSP? The configuration is a little bit different than using .tag files:

**web.xml**

```
<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>mytaglib</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/mytaglib.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    ...
</jsp-config>
```

**mytaglib.tld**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd">

    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>mylib</short-name>
    <uri>/WEB-INF/tags/mytaglib</uri>
    <tag>
        <name>checkbox</name>
        <tag-class>com.myapp.tag.MyTagSupport</tag-class>
        <body-content>empty</body-content>
        <attribute>
            <name>name</name>
            <required>true</required>
            <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
        </attribute>
        ...
    </tag>
    ...
</taglib>
```

**JSP Include**

```
<%@taglib uri="mytaglib" prefix="ml" %>
```

**Tag Support Class**

```
package com.myapp.tag;

import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport    

public class MyTagSuppoort extends BodyTagSupport {

    private String name = name;

    // Values are autowired by the JSTL API
    public void setName ( String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

This is a decent example of how to implement things in your tag support class too:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm